# SVG animation endEvent not firing after migrating from Vue 2 to Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, quasar-framework, svg-animate

I'm currently migrating a vue 2 / Quasar 1 project to vue 3 / Quasar 2 and I'm struggling with an event on an SVG animation element that doesn't seem to fire in the new version....

```
<animateTransform
    begin="startAnimation.begin"
    attributeName="transform"
    attributeType="XML"
    type="rotate"
    from="-18 150 380"
    to="0 150 380"
    dur="0.6s"
    repeatCount="1"
    fill="freeze"
    calcMode="spline"
    keySplines="0.3 0.7 0.3 0.7"
    keyTimes="0;1"
    @endEvent="animationEndHandler()"
/>
```

The endEvent event (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGAnimationElement/endEvent_event) works fine in the old version but nothing happens in the new one. Everything else is the same and I have tried reducing the animationEndHandler method to nothing but a console.log('hello')

I've tried in Chrome and Safari on Mac, and built with Cordova for iOS, so I'm confident it's not a browser issue as the old version works in the same browsers.

Just because I ran out of anything else to try, I tried all of the following too...

```
@endEvent="animationEndHandler"
@endevent="animationEndHandler"
@end-event="animationEndHandler"
@endevent="animationEndHandler()"
@end-event="animationEndHandler()"
v-on:endEvent="animationEndHandler()"
v-on:endEvent="animationEndHandler"
v-on:endevent="animationEndHandler()"
v-on:endevent="animationEndHandler"
v-on:end-event="animationEndHandler()"
v-on:end-event="animationEndHandler"
```

When I inspect the `<animateTransform>` element in chrome dev tools and look in the Event Listeners tab on the right hand side I can see "endevent" in there, and my `animationEndHandler` referenced in the handler, but it never seems to get called.

If anyone can offer any suggestions as to why this no longer works under Vue 3 I would be massively grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is not clear to me (perhaps a Vue 3 bug), but you could workaround it by declaring your own [custom directive](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html) that mimics [`v-on`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on) (for which the `@` is shorthand).

For example, locally register a directive, named `on2`:

```js
export default {
  directives: {
    on2(el, binding) {
      // <div v-on2:foo="bar">  ->  binding = { arg: 'foo', value: this.bar }
      el.addEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value);
    },
  },
}
```

Or globally register the directive:

```js
createApp(...)
  .directive('on2', (el, binding) => {
    el.addEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value);
  })
  .mount('#app')
```

And use it in your template:

```html
<animateTransform v-on2:endEvent="animationEndHandler" />
```

[Vue 3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/listen-to-endevent-from-animatetransform-forked-jtd07?file=/src/App.vue:674-779)

Answer (score 0):

Try `:endEvent="animationEndHandler()"`

Ran in the the same problem and think I know why. The SVG elements don't use the standard `addEventListener` method but rather attributes that are set. You can set it with the standard attribute setter.

Heres a fiddle to demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L5om97dr/1/